# Can't login with Paypal Sandbox account

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, sandbox

I'm working on setting up a `Drupal` `commerce` website with `Paypal` support for which I have registered a business `Paypal` account. Now, with the business `Paypal` account, I have created sandbox accounts for testing, they show up like 
`info-facilitator@inetgate.biz` and `info-buyer@inetgate.biz` under https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts 
but If I either try to run through a payment example and try to use `info-buyer@inetgate.biz` for the buyer account, it doesn't let me sign in nor does paypal let me sign into my `facilitator` account when I click the `Enter Sandbox site` link on my `Sandbox test accounts` page. Why is this, what am I missing?

Thank you!

**EDIT 1**

ASorry, I didn't describe:

> nor does paypal let me sign into my `facilitator` account

means that I get the following message when I enter the email `info-facilitator@inetgate.biz` plus the password from my business account:

**Please make sure you enter your email address and password correctly. If you still can't log in, please see the Troubleshooting Tips below.**

Comment: when you say it doesn't let you, what happens?

Comment: For the sandbox site login part, as a sanity check, use "Incognito" mode if you have Chrome (or similar in other browsers).

Comment: @AndrewAngell please see **EDIT 1** above

Comment: @EdSF I tried incognito mode but I get the same error as described above in **EDIT 1**

Answer (score 7):

Turns out I had to manually create a facilitator and a buyer account by pressing the button **CREATE ACCOUNT**, the ones that were automatically created didn't let me sign-in but once I created my own accounts, things started working as expected!
Thanks for everyone's time spent on this issue!

Comment: Same issue for me. I really don't get why this is not already fixed and why this happens at all for a big company like Paypal. This is *very* disappointing. Guess I'll evaluate Stripe now which is praised by a lot devs...

Comment: Thanks. Paypal's documentation in general is veeeery bad.

Answer (score 0):

It turns that paypal default facilitator and buyer accounts doesn't have a password. You have to go to the profile settings and hit change password for both -facilitator@ and -buyer@. Then it will work as expected.

Comment: Until those stop working for no reason. Which is like 90% of PayPal in general anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out I was logging my merchant and buyer sandbox accounts to 
https://www.paypal.com/in/signin .Make sure you log in your sandbox accounts to 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com. This worked for me.